# PhoneGap Build: Most likely config.xml for Android to crash

Tags: android, xml, phonegap-build

Well, sorry for the quite generic question. The client wants privacy.
But let me explain:

The Code runs perfectly inside the browser for iOS as well as Android. The iOS (.ipa) version also runs like a charm.

But somehow the Android version (.apk) crashes while launching the app. Since HTML usually doesn't do that (and also doesn't crash the browser), I suppose it has to do something with the config.

Here is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id        = "com.***.***"
    versionCode=""
    version   = "">
    <name>***</name>
    <description>******</description>
    <author href="http://www.***.com" email="info@***.com">***</author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen " value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView " value="true" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="windows-identity-name" value="" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value="null" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value="," />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="null" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />


    <platform name="ios">

        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="156" height="156" />

        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Portrait-763@3x.png" width="1242" height="2208" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape-763@3x.png" width="2208" height="1242" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-667h@2x.png" width="750" height="1334" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" width="640" height="1136" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" /> 
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default@2x.png" width="640" height="960" /> 

    </platform>

    <platform name="android">

        <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" qualifier="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" qualifier="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" qualifier="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" qualifier="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" qualifier="xxxhdpi" />

        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-ldpi.png" qualifier="port-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-mdpi.png" qualifier="port-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-hdpi.png" qualifier="port-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-xhdpi.png" qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-xxhdpi.png" qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/port-xxxhdpi.png" qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-ldpi.png" qualifier="land-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-mdpi.png" qualifier="land-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-hdpi.png" qualifier="land-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-xhdpi.png" qualifier="land-xhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-xxhdpi.png" qualifier="land-xxhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splash/android/land-xxxhdpi.png" qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" />

    </platform>

<!--
    <platform name="winphone">
    </platform>
-->

    <access origin="www.***.***" subdomains="true" />
</widget>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the Error Log from Android Studio

```
22867-22867/com.***.*** E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.***.***/com.***.***.***}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
            at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
            at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
            at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:176)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences.getInteger(CordovaPreferences.java:78)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:146)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:220)
            at com.***.***.***.onCreate(***.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What crash is their when app runs ?

Comment: @jaydroider "Unfortunately, *** has stopped."

Comment: What browser logs are showing ?

Comment: If you mean the browser console, there are absolutely no errors.

Comment: Any uncaught exception in android logs ? If not then check your internet connection.

Comment: check error logs in android studio while crash app, there is definitely some error log for crash...

Comment: @Naitik Ho do you remote log a process which isn't running with Android Studio?

Comment: but app crashed android can fetch in android studio wether app is running from android studio or not, you will get logs in studio, please google about it and check logs to get error

Comment: @Naitik Ah got it, it says `E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Search in logs something like `uncaught error` or `uncaught exception`. you will find it in android logs.

Comment: ok then you can search more about error on google, and please check network permssion in android mainfest.xml file

Comment: @Naitik I added the `FATAL ERROR` to the question because it's quite long ;)

Comment: one standard trick if you can do, please remove platform android and add again and try, am not sure it will help or not but atleast you can try, please be aware any native changes directly in platform folder will deleted...

Comment: @Naitik The one standard trick didn't do it's magic... Causing the exact same error.

Comment: please use **<access origin="*"/>**

Comment: still issue persist please remove **<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000" />** and check....

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `access origin`. Also, I already tried this out with the `BackgroundColor` by moving it into the iOS section. Well, I also tried removing all the preference tags **and then the app worked**. So it has to be one of the tags, but I have no idea which one. Is there a good documentation which states which preference is for which OS?

Comment: not cover all but http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/

Comment: try rmove one by one and try 1) **<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />** 2)  **<preference name="LoadingDialog" value="," />**

Comment: https://github.com/kkirby/Cordova-Config-Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the lovely help of Naitik I could finally find the malicious line. But instead of deleting each line one by one and uploading it to Adobe and then downloading it and so on, I saved a lot of time by deleting half of the lines. If the test turned positive, I split the positive half into halves and tested each half and so on until I could narrow it down to following line:

```
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="null" />
```

Removed it.
Didn't expect it there, but now it works. Thanks to all who helped!